# WebRTC/Socket.io Connecting two Clients / Signaling

Tags: webrtc

I've updated my code with the complete signaling exchange. The problem now, is that upon completing the exchange, "socket.on('receivedAnswer')" throws an error. I'm testing all this on my local machine in two browser tabs so I assume I don't need ICE just yet for this to work...

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href= 'css.css'>
<script src="node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='video_box'>
<video id= 'video' autoplay="true">
</video>
</div>
<div id='video_box2'>
<video id='video2' autoplay="true">
</video>
<div>
<script>
    var local_stream;
    var baseURL = getBaseURL();
    var socketIOPort = 8999;
    var socketIOLocation = baseURL + socketIOPort;
    var socket = io(socketIOLocation);
    var localvid = document.getElementById('video');
    var mediaOptions = { audio: false, video: true };
    var pc = new mozRTCPeerConnection( {"iceServers": [{"url": "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302" }] });
    var pc2 = new mozRTCPeerConnection();
    var PeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var SessionDescription = window.RTCSessionDescription || window.mozRTCSessionDescription || window.webkitRTCSessionDescription;
    var offerConstraints = {OfferToReceiveAudio: true, OfferToReceiveVideo: true }

    socket.on('receivedAnswer', function(answerSDP){
        pc.setRemoteDescription(new mozRTCSessionDescription(answerSDP), function(){
            alert('received the answer');
        }, error2);
    });

    socket.on('getPeer1', function(SDP) {
        alert('got peer 1 SDP');
        pc.setRemoteDescription(new mozRTCSessionDescription(SDP), function() { 
            pc.createAnswer(function(answerSDP){
                pc.setLocalDescription(answerSDP, function() {
                    socket.emit('answerSDP', answerSDP);
                    alert('sending answer');
                }, error2);
            }, error2);
        }, error2);
    });

    function start(){
        checkMedia();
        navigator.getUserMedia(mediaOptions, getMediaSuccess, error2);
    }

    function answer(offeredSDP){
        offeredSDP = new SessionDescription(offeredSDP);
    }

    function peer(){
        pc.addStream(local_stream);
        pc.createOffer(function(SDP){
            socket.emit('sendSDPtoServer', SDP);
        }, error2, offerConstraints);
    }

    function getMediaSuccess(stream){
        localvid.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        local_stream = stream;
        peer(); ///////////
    }

    function error2(){
        alert('error');
    }


    function error3(){
        alert('error here');
    }

    function checkMedia() {
        if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
        }
        if (!navigator.getUserMedia){
            alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.');
        }
    }

    function getBaseURL(){
        baseURL = location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + ":" + location.port;
        return baseURL;
    }

start();
//alert('script');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server

```
var static = require('node-static');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 8999;
var http = require('http');
var file= new(static.Server)();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
var connectedClients = {};
var peer1 = 0;
var peer2 = 0;
var peer1sdp = 0;
var peer2sdp = 0;

app.set('views', __dirname)
    .engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)
    .use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
    .get('/', function(req, res) {
        //res.render('indexcpy.html');
    });




io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');

        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            console.log('user disconnected');
        });

        socket.on('answerSDP', function(answerSDP){
            console.log('ANSWER SENT');
            io.to(peer1).emit('receivedAnswer', answerSDP);
        });

        socket.on('sendSDPtoServer', function(SDP) {
            if(peer1 == 0){
                console.log('peer 1 ' + socket.id + ' has sent its SDP to server'); 
                peer1 = socket.id;
                peer1sdp = SDP;
            } else {
                console.log('peer 2 ' + socket.id + ' has been sent to the server');
                socket.emit('getPeer1', peer1sdp);
            }
        });



});
```

Answer (score 2):

the mistake here is your assumption that, `pc.addStream(stream)` would fire `pc.onstream(event)` on the same peer, but it would actually be fired on the remote peer.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onaddstream#Values)

other that that, your `webrtc` code is incomplete, while your offer SDP reaches the server, it is not sent to the remote peer and also it's answer has to be forwarded to your peer and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that before creating  Answer your local stream is added to the peerconnection. It will be more clear if you show where you are generating the answer